# How do I smooth data in maple?

Tags: maple, curvesmoothing

In maple, what is the best way to smooth a data set, similar to one shown in the diagram, to get a regular(smooth) curve without affecting overall statistical properties? I am using Maple 16.

[image: xdata has 120 bins from 0.05 to 6.00]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend having a look at the [data smoothing](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics/DataSmoothing) commands in the [Statistics](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics) package. Something like an [exponential smoothing model](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics/ExponentialSmoothing) could be applied to your data in order to smooth out the trend line.

If you have a recent copy of Maple, you can experiment with this using something like the following:

```
with(Statistics):
Z := Sample(Normal(0, 1), 50): #Generate some data
Y := CumulativeSum(Z):
ESmodel := Constant -> ExponentialSmoothing(Y, 0.1*Constant):
```

The [Explore](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Explore) command creates an interface where you can try out different values for a smoothing constant:

```
Explore( plots[display]( LineChart(Y, color=blue), 
                         LineChart(ESmodel(Constant), thickness=3, color=red),  
          gridlines=true),
parameters=[Constant=1..10] );
```

[image: Explore_Smoothing_Example]